# Classification: training sets different sizes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, natural-language, naive-bayes, sentiment-analysis

I'm building a classifier for text analysis sentiment.

I have a large training set for positive, neutral and negative mentions.

Should the training data sets be similar in size? Currently my training set for 'neutral' is about 10x larger than the set for 'positive' and 'neutral'.

On a side note - when the classifier encounters a new word that doesn't occur in either of the 3 training sets, how do I assign a probability to the word that takes into account the different training set sizes?

Comment: What do you mean assign probability? You want the model to do it right?

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. 

My model should assign a non-zero probability to a new word (that doesn't occur in either of the 3 training sets).

The probability that a new word belongs to the class "positive" is in inverse proportion to the amount of words currently in the "positive" training set. This holds true for 'neutral' and 'negative' as well. 

Now, if my 'neutral' set is so much larger than my 'positive' set, the model assigns a lower probability to the new word belonging to 'neutral', even though the probability is higher. 

How do I compensate for this?

Answer (score -1):

It is always preferable for the dataset to be equal for each class. As you indicated, if the neutral dataset is that high compared to others, most probably your model will overfit to the neutral data which is not desired.

Comment: Then again, the a priori probability that a new piece of test data belongs to 'neutral' is also much higher than for 'positive' or 'negative'.

Comment: Maybe you should upsample the minority classes and downsample the majority class (SMOTE Technique or other), you need a relatively even set of possible outcomes to be classified, otherwise it happens as Pieter says.

Comment: It is not always preferable for the dataset to be equal for each class.  Bayes rule says that P(class|attributues) = P(attributes|class)p(class)/p(attributes), so the classifier needs to be able to infer p(class) in order to behave optimally.  p(class) is the probability of the class in operational use.  The easiest way for the classifier to learn this is for the proportions of patterns of each class in the training data to be the same as the proportion in operational use.